# Testing type of union variable without verifying properties

Tags: functional-programming, flowtype

I'm trying to check for the type of the value of a variable of union type.

```js
/* @flow */

type A = {
  a: number, 
  b: number
}

type B = {
  c: string
}

const fun1: (A | B) => void = (x) => {
  if (x.a) {
    x.a
    x.b // Doesn't work
  }
  if (x.b) {
    x.b
    x.a // Doesn't work
  }
  if (x.c) {
    x.c
  }
}
```

Is the only way to do so by checking for individual properties? In the example above, it's known that if `x.a`, then also `x.b`. Is there no way of checking for a `A` type or `B` type so I could write

```js
const fun1: (A | B) => void = (x) => {
  if (typeof x === 'A') { // Cannot compare the result of `typeof` to string literal `A` because it is not a valid `typeof` return value.
    x.a // Works
    x.b // Works
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is failing because Flow object types by default allow unspecified properties, so for example the following is fine:

```
let a: A = {
  a: 1,
  b: 2,
  c: "",
};
```

so an `A` type may well *also* qualify as a `B` type, with your current definitions.

To avoid this, you need to make `A` and `B` [exact object types](https://flow.org/en/docs/types/objects/#toc-exact-object-types), so Flow knows that they don't allow additional random properties. e.g.

```
type A = {|
  a: number, 
  b: number
|}

type B = {|
  c: string
|}
```